# Can't return concrete type with generic argument in extension method

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

How can I create such createFetcher method returning object under the generic protocol? Can't understand what's unclear here to compiler. Such approach worked fine without associatedtype in protocol.
Below code won't compile with error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'DecoratorAsyncFetcher<Self.DataType>' to return type 'Fetcher'

```
protocol SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    associatedtype DataType
    func fetch() async throws -> DataType
}

extension SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    func createFetcher<Fetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol>(with fetcher: Fetcher) -> Fetcher where Fetcher.DataType == DataType {
        DecoratorAsyncFetcher<DataType>(self, reliefFetcher: fetcher) //Cannot convert.....
    }
}

struct DecoratorAsyncFetcher<D>: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    typealias DataType = D
    
    init<Fetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol>(_ fetcher: Fetcher, reliefFetcher: Fetcher) where Fetcher.DataType == DataType {
        //Some setup
    }
    
    func fetch() async throws -> DataType {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

**PS: Some explanations.**

For Petar that said: `SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol is a protocol - you can not create an instance of a protocol to be returned anywhere`. Here is the code where method DOES return protocol and compiles well. It CAN create and CAN return protocol. So, my above question — I want to achieve the same but with associated type.

```
protocol SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    func fetch() async throws -> String
}

extension SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    func createFetcher(with fetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol) -> SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
        DecoratorAsyncFetcher(self, reliefFetcher: fetcher)
    }
}

struct DecoratorAsyncFetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    init(_ fetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol, reliefFetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol) {
        //Some setup
    }
    
    func fetch() async throws -> String {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have updated the question. Sorry, tried to simplify, but your suggestion works in simplified version and does not work in full version...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, that's the main thing I need, sure. I need all fetchers of exactly same type, that's the point of decorator to keep type after decoration.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to chain SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol objects and get SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol with same DataType on output.

Comment: Not sure I understand which statement was different)) I believe just a clarification. I need to take several SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol and pack them into another SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol of same underlying associatedtype.

Comment: No, not concrete type. I am using protocol here. Same abstract type.

Comment: Why do you think it's not what I want?)))

Comment: Why I can't if I can. It perfectly works on that stage. Did you try to compile?

Comment: More than that, my example perfectly works in production in case without associatedtype, as I mentioned in the question btw.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here ? DecoratorAsyncFetcher conforms to SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol and is itself being initialized with an instance of SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol - this seems odd and I cannot understand what is your goal here.

Comment: I just want to achieve what's in question. I need to return SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol in createFetcher method

Comment: your DecoratorAsyncFetcher is messed up. This struct's initializer expects a parameter of the type of the struct itself - this is odd and is confusing. So firstly I'd work around that, and then I'd think about a factory method to initialize the DecoratorAsyncFetcher instead of doing that in the protocol extension.  If you give me an overview of what your requirement is I could advise on how to structure this code better

Comment: Thank you, but I did ask the above question, and did not ask about helping with architecture. I have a factory and it’s factory will create the specific chain of SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol or just it’s realizations. Why I need to somehow replace that chaining with the fabric? They will work together. Thank you again, but please, understand that I am asking a specific question. I don’t need suggestions like “you don’t need to do like that, your approach and architecture is wrong”. I did not show anything around that piece of code. Only specific question, thanks.

Comment: Yes and I am trying to explain that if you think about your architecture a bit further you could understand that your question is not applicable any more. What you have in the code above is meaningless and obviously Swift cannot compile it.

Comment: I know that Swift can't compile it. That's the function of Stackoverflow to ask questions about also the code that cannot compile. I did not ask your opinion about my architecture, and you even did not see it. Please let's discuss only particular question. If you don't know how to modify the above code to make it able to compile, then you can just don't reply here. Again, I don't ask anybody about my architecture lol)))

Comment: if you want a meaningful answer, you should ask a meaningful question - this is the function of SO. As I said, I could modify your code if I knew what is its requirement - if you are unable to specify what exactly you want your code to do then this whole discussion and question is redundant.

Comment: I need to return SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol in createFetcher method.

Comment: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol is a protocol - you can not create an instance of a protocol to be returned anywhere. The createFetcher returning the type of the protocol in an extension of the protocol won't work hence I advised to come up with a factory method to create your instance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting the `Cannot convert return expression of type 'DecoratorAsyncFetcher<Self.DataType>' to return type 'Fetcher'` error is due to the fact that the generic parameter in the `createFetcher` function and the generic parameter in the `DecoratorAsyncFetcher` initializer may not be of the same type.

There are two things that are wrong here:

Even if you try to create an instance of `DecoratorAsyncFetcher` in the `createFetcher` method

```
let decorator = DecoratorAsyncFetcher<DataType>(self, reliefFetcher: fetcher)
```

the compiler will complain because it expects that Self and reliefFetcher are of the same type. It might look like they are from the same type but consider this:

```
struct BasicAsyncFetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    typealias DataType = String

    func fetch() async throws -> String {
        fatalError()
    }
}

struct AdvancedAsyncFetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol {
    typealias DataType = String

    func fetch() async throws -> String {
        fatalError()
    }
}


let basicFetcher = BasicAsyncFetcher()
let advancedFetcher = AdvancedAsyncFetcher()

let decoratorFetcher = basicFetcher.createFetcher(with: advancedFetcher)
```

Now what would you expect the type of `decoratorFetcher` to be ? Is it going to be a `BasicAsyncFetcher` or `AdvancedAsyncFetcher` ? The compiler does not know since when it tries to resolve the generic type of the initializer of `DecoratorAsyncFetcher` it can be either `BasicAsyncFetcher` or `AdvancedAsyncFetcher`

To fix this issue we can change the initializer of the Decorator to

```
init(_ fetcher: any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol, reliefFetcher: any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol)
```

Now we can create an instance of `DecoratorAsyncFetcher` and it will be evaluated properly. However, the error `Cannot convert return expression of type ...` remains if we try to return that instance.

If we call `createFetcher` on the `BasicAsyncFetcher` instance using the `AdvancedAsyncFetcher` as parameter, the generic parameter `Fetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol` will be evaluated to `AdvancedAsyncFetcher` since the compiler must eventually resolve it to a concrete type. Hence, the function's return type will be `AdvancedAsyncFetcher` but we are returning `DecoratorAsyncFetcher`. The compiler doesn't know the concrete type of Fetcher and will show that error.

This could be fixed if we change the method to

```
func createFetcher<Fetcher: SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol>(with reliefFetcher: Fetcher) -> any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol
```

Now the type of our `decoratorFetcher` will be correctly determined to be `SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol` which is what I believe you want to achieve here. Also note that the associatedType in the protocol has nothing to do with the compiler errors.

Comment: First of all, inside my Decorator there is not a Composite. It's a Chain of Responsibility. So basically there is 2 patterns here. Decorator — is a structural design pattern that lets you attach new behaviors to objects by placing these objects inside special wrapper objects that contain the behaviors. Chain of Responsibility — is a behavioral design pattern that lets you pass requests along a chain of handlers. Upon receiving a request, each handler decides either to process the request or to pass it to the next handler in the chain.

Comment: But you did not see my logic inside as I said I will not show my architecture, that's no matter for my question at all.

Comment: Regarding your `you can not create an instance of a protocol to be returned anywhere` — I've added an explanation to the question where I CAN.

Comment: You are not returning an instance of a protocol since this concept does not exist  - you are returning a concrete type which conforms to your protocol - these are different things. Regardless, this is beyond the scope of this question and the answer provided, so if you think this answer has solved your problem please accept it, otherwise explain what is missing from the answer.

Comment: I understand that. But my returning type is PROTOCOL which I want. Look at the working example, the return type is protocol there.

Comment: The question was how to get protocol with specified type as the return type. I can't accept the solution with returning Any as data type. If there is no solution at all, I am ok with that. I just don't need to get Any type, for sure not an option. Thank you for your effort very much, but there is no solution mentioned in your answer unfortunately.

Comment: @bodich If you read it more carefully you will see that the first part is where I try to explain what your problem is. The second part was added as a suggestion which I will now remove so its clearer. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I just don't have any solution here, that's all. Maybe Swift can't compile that yet, maybe will be updated further, maybe we just can't find solution which exists. But for sure no any solution for specific question was found here in thread yet. It does not mean I have any issues. I don't have any.

Comment: @bodich If you change your code with what I posted you will no longer have the compiler error.

Comment: I don't need another code. I can create such code by myself. I've posted a clear question about making my example work. Thank you for trying to help, but I just don't need any advice kinda "wrong solution, use another one". It's like answering the question "how to repare the wheel on my Volkswagen" with the answer "Why are you using Volkswagen, buy Toyota and you don't need sedan, only use off-road" etc. I believe my question is clear, please let's not waste time. I don't need Toyota, I need to repair wheel on Volkswagen. Especially your solution won't work further in real life, only compile.

Comment: @bodich I have given you a precise answer to your precise question - just change your initializer and the extension method to as I suggested and you will obtain the behaviour you want without the compiler complaining

Comment: No, this does not work as per requirements. When I return any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol, I have Any type as the result of fetcher.fetch() call. I have any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol that can't be used anywhere when I have type constraints. I don't need a chain of Any something. I need type safety, please look at the question which contains type constraints in return type.

Comment: any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol is not Any type. Type constraint is inferred by the type you use when calling the function. You want to have an instance of type SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol  and you get an instance of type SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol - not sure what additional requirement you have

Comment: fetch() method of any SimpleAsyncFetcherProtocol returns Any type

Comment: You've asked "How can I create such createFetcher method returning object under the generic protocol? Can't understand what's unclear here to compiler. " - I did explain in my answer what is unclear to the compiler. If this doesn't answer your problem then either update your question or if there is an (as it seems) additional question then  you can make a new post for it.

Comment: The code in question clearly says that return type is Fetcher where Fetcher.DataType == DataType. What's unclear here? If you don't understand the difference when resulting fetcher will return Any or DataType in it's fetch() method then ok, just skip this thread.

Comment: What do you want the type of `decoratorFetcher` as per the example above `let decoratorFetcher = basicFetcher.createFetcher(with: advancedFetcher)` to be ?

Comment: Not sure why do you have to be so rude - I have only been trying to help because the subject is interesting for me too. Obviously your question does not clearly specify how you want to be using your createFetcher function. I am not forcing you to do anything, I am simply trying to make you specify exactly what you want - so if you are unable to answer my question from above - what the type of `decoratorFetcher` should be then its all pointless really.

Comment: I answered a lot of times.

Comment: Ok so then it is not possible :D good luck